# Can a Geiger counter detect backscatter x ray?

Tags: experimental-physics, radiation, x-rays, particle-detectors

Assume Backscatter x ray pointed at a person through three brick walls, 4 inch each, creating real time video at 10-20 FPS of person moving.

Can backscatter x-ray show real color images (if connected to computer or built in features)?

How much energy, wavelength and electricity consumptions (in watts) to able to see through brick walls?

Can backscatter x-ray show whats written on hard documents or computer monitor?

Is it possible x-ray can run for 24/7/365.

How much radiation can Geiger counter detect through three brick walls?

Answer (score 1):

Geiger counters have neither position sensitivity (outside of hit the counter or not) nor direction sensitivity nor energy sensitivity.

They are not imaging sensors in any sense.

But to answer the question in the title *"Can a Geiger counter detect backscatter x ray?"*, the counters will detect any photon radiation of sufficient energy, and are perfectly happy to include backscatter photons in that set.

Comment: And most of the backscatter it detects will be from the wall, not what's behind it...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by dmckee, your question about how much radiation a Geiger counter can detect thru 3 brick walls should really be stated as how much radiation can penetrate 3 brick walls. This depends on the energy and intensity of the radiation. The Geiger counter will be sensitive to this radiation.

Xrays are outside the frequency region of visible light and hence they have no color by our concept of color. Xrays can be imaged but not with a Geiger counter.  A false-color spectrum could be applied to an x-ray image but the colors, as stated, are false and just used to distinguish xrays of different energy region.

Comment: Actually since this is backscatter, the question is how much radiation penetrates six walls - and how can you distinguish that from radiation that actually scattered off the wall and not from what's behind. That sounds like a very ugly SNR.